# Django media file path is incorrect, missing a directory

Tags: python, django, django-models

Currently using Django 1.9.
Image files in my model are uploading properly to

> project\media\FILEPATH.jpg

However, images are attempting to be displayed using the filepath without \media. For example, when I go to my localhost http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/FILEPATH.jpg in my browser, I get a 404 because Django's get request is looking for:

> project\FILEPATH.jpg

How do I get django to serve my media files properly with \media\?

---

More information if it may be of any use:
settings.py:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'))
```

model:
`image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media', blank='true')`

project urls.py I have the following after urlpatterns as per the documentation:

`static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

Thank you for any help!

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
  ptype = models.ForeignKey('blog.Type', related_name='posts')
  title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
  text = models.TextField()
  published_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.title
class Image(models.Model):
  post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', related_name='images')
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media', blank='true')
```

views.py

```
class Posts(generic.ListView):
  model = Post
  context_object_name = 'posts'
  template_name = 'blog/posts.html'
```

posts.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}

{% for post in posts %}
  <p><a href = "{% url 'blog:postdetail' pk=post.pk %}">{{post.title}}</a></p>
  <p>{{post.text}}</p>
  {% for image in post.image_set.all %}
    <img src="{{ image.image.url }}">
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: post the html part. Could it be that you forgot to add `.url` to the `src`attribute? For example: `<img src="{{ user.userprofile.image.url }}">`

Comment: @hansTheFranz I added a lot more context to the question. Appreciate the response.

Comment: I can imagine that the keyword `image` in `{% for image in post.image_set.all %}` could confuse Python I would simply call it `x`. When you use `<img src="{{ image.image.url }}">` the first `image` refers to the four loop variable not the model you defined. Or at least I think the problem could be there. What happens if you change `image` to `x` in the foot loop(just there not in the `src` part) and what happens when you don't delete the for loop? Is the url correct?

Comment: @hansTheFranz After some more tinkering upon your suggestion, I have gotten the images to display with the following code:     {% for x in post.images.all %}
      <img src="{{ x.image.url }}">
    {% endfor %}  THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP! I really don't understand why this works, and apparently my media files paths are /media/media/sav2017.jpg rather than just /media. But I will further investigate. Thanks again. It's working now atleast, I just have to figure out why.

Comment: Yeah no problem, glad to help somebody get started :)

Comment: @hansTheFranz I also realized that my main error stemmed from me coding image_set.all. I had overwritten the name with the `related_name` attribute on the model. Image.image still ends up working, but I have changed it for clarity purposes. Thanks again and have a great day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok

When your declare the upload on the model, Django detect automatically that your route of media is BASE_DIR/media, when you put somthing in upload_to on the model you are declare that this image have to saved on BASE_DIR/media/something

Example: if I want to save the user's images into media I have to make this on the model

```
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/', blank='true')
```

and my image will saved on localhost/media/users/FILEPATH.jpg

All this url after media/ is saved on your field of 'image' so your image field will say just 'users/FILEPATH.jpg' but not the localhost/media/

Thats why you need to write the /media/ in you src

```
 <img src="/media/{{ image.image }}">
```

and if you save the image on the field named 'image' your will not need the .url.

Try it.

Comment: I see what you are saying. The upload_to attribute already recognizes the location of media, which is why I could not figure out my paths because it was searching for /media/media. I have altered my upload_to to include a sub directory which makes much more sense. Thank you for your help!!!!